# How do generically handle mvc.net ajax errors

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

My mvc.net website uses ajax pretty extensively. Up until now I have been handling ajax errors on an individual basis, but for the most part I am always doing the same thing.

For jquery ajax calls, I am setting the ajaxSetup error configuration so that it does what I want it to do. Unfortunately that doesn't seem to do much when I am using an ActionLink or ajax form with razor. For those, I have to set the AjaxOptions for OnFailure to some javascript method.

While I could just point them all to the same method, I would like to be able to do this without having to explicitly set the AjaxOptions. Is there a way to make it so that all mvc.net ajax calls use the same event handlers (unless overridden), similar to how jquery allows you to do it?

I am sure this question has been asked before but I haven't seen any good solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can create a static method in C# to create an instance of AjaxOptions class, and set the error handler there.

```
public static class AjaxHelper
{
    public static AjaxOptions GetAjaxOptions(string onSuccess) 
    {
       var ajaxOptions = new AjaxOptions();
       ajaxOptions.OnSuccess = onSuccess;
       // your generic js function that will handle errors.
       ajaxOptions.OnError = "genericAjaxErrorHandler";
       return ajaxOptions;
    }
}
```

than in your view you can just invoke it when creating ajax form.

```
@using(Ajax.BeginForm(...., AjaxHelper.GetAjaxOptions("successHandler")) {}
```

and you will not have to specify error handlers everywhere...

Comment: That's certainly an idea I haven't considered, but in this case I still have to specify AjaxOptions every time I use a form or link. Its only a little better than explicitly setting OnFailure = "HandleError". Ill do this if it turns out that there really isn't a way to do it without specifying AjaxOptions. Thanks for the idea